# PostgreSQL: Cómo usar la función DATE_PART junto con WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quiero obtener todos los registros de una tabla relativos al mes de setiembre. Estoy usando PostgreSQL.

La siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT date_part('month', field);
```

me devuelve una columna llamada `date_part` con los enteros representando el mes.

Sin embargo, todas estas tentativas me retornan un error diciendo que la columna no existe:

```
SELECT date_part('month', field) FROM table WHERE date_part=9;

SELECT date_part('month', field) FROM table WHERE month=9;

SELECT date_part('month', field) AS month FROM table WHERE month=9;
```

En qué estoy errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date_part es una función por ende en el where debes realizar de nuevo el llamado a la función con los parámetros y al resultado le aplicas la igualdad.

```
SELECT date_part('month', field) FROM table WHERE date_part('month', field)=9;
```

Comment: Agrego que usualmente en éstos casos se hace un indice para que la función no se ejecute constantemente, debes leer sobre la creación de los mismo.. Te dejo un enlace: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/function_based_indexes